# email form with attachment via PHP - PDF output random words

Tags: php, forms, email, file-upload, email-attachments

I wanted to send an attachment with form email via PHP, I got the email part working but unfortunately when I attach the PDF file (attachment) and try to send it, the PDF file does not send and it output a long paragraph of random words.

Below is my code, please do advise me what is wrong and how to make it better.

Your time and advice are much appreciated.

```
 <?php
 
 $message_sent = false;
   if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
         if(!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name'])){  
             $file_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];  
             $temp_name = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];  
             $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
          
            $base = basename($file_name);
            $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));
          
            //only these file types will be allowed
        $allowed_extensions = array(".doc", "docx", ".pdf", ".zip", ".png"); 
            //check that this file type is allowed
             if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)) {
> 
>                 //mailto code
>                 if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !='') {
>             
>                  if(filter_var($_POST ['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
>                 
>                 //submit the form
>                 $ClientName = $_POST ['name'];
>                 $ClientEmail = $_POST ['email'];
>                 $ClientSubject = $_POST ['subject'];
>                 $ClientWords = $_POST ['words'];
>                 $ClientTime = $_POST ['time']; 
>                 $ClientTranslation = $_POST ['translation'];
>                 $ClientMessage = $_POST ['message'];
>             
>                 $to = "(my email)";
>                 $body = "";
> 
>                 //things u need
>                 $file = $temp_name;
>                 $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
>                 $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier
> 
>                 
> 
>                 //declare multiple kinds of email (plain text + attch)
>                 $header .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";
>                 $header .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
>                 
>                 
> 
>                 //attch part
>                 $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
>                 $header .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
>                 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
>                 $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
>                 $header .= $content."\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch
>             
>                 $body .= "From: ".$ClientName. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "Email: ".$ClientEmail. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "Subject: ".$ClientSubject. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "Words: ".$ClientWords. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "Time: ".$ClientTime. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "TranslationUse: ".$ClientTranslation. "\r\n";
>                 $body .= "Message: ".$ClientMessage. "\r\n";
>             
>                 mail($to, $ClientSubject, $body, $header);
> 
>                 $message_sent = true; 
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     $invalid_class_name = "form-invalid";
>                 }  
>             
>             }
> 
>             }
> 
>         }
>     }
>         
>     ?>
> 
> (few HTML codes of the form I tried to create)
> 
>  <?php
>         if($message_sent):
>     ?>
>         <h3 class="pt-5">Thank you, we'll be intouch soon.</h3>
> 
>     <?php
>         else:
>     ?> (End of the form I tried to create)
>      
>     <?php
>         endif;
>     ?>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please format your question so all of your code is visible. Thanks

Comment: ok, how do I do that, please?

Comment: [Edit] your question and use the formatting buttons at the top. Use `code` instead of `blockquotes` for code

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `From:` and `Reply-To:` lines should be part of the headers and not the body. Perhaps you should also add the `MIME-Version: 1.0` header. I also think that `Message:` cannot be used like that. Actually, if you are sending a multipart mail then the message itself should be split with your `$uid` also. You could also use a library such as [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Symfony Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html).

Comment: Use PhpMailer, and save yourself this world of pain. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @PatrickJanser thank you for your reply. I will try it out